# Simulate more RAM with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, optimization

**Background:** I'm in the process of optimizing a Data Warehouse style query with big dimension tables. The optimizer does not like to pick the typical star schema join plan at the moment. When I force this plan (by using an index hint) I can see that this star join plan is just a little more expensive than the plan I'm using right now. I suspect that is because the dimensions do not fit into RAM on my development machine. The version is SQL Server 2014 but I hope that the question can be generalized to all recent versions.

**Question:** Is there a way to make the optimizer believe that it has a lot of RAM at its disposal? For testing purposes I would like to obtain the plan that it would generate if it had 1TB of RAM available (instead of 8GB at the moment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DBCC WHATIF`](http://sqlity.net/en/828/optimizer-what-if-i-had-more-cpus/) command (also see http://devondba.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/dbcc-optimizerwhatif.html) can be used to simulate a certain hardware configuration for the current session:

```
dbcc OPTIMIZER_WHATIF ({property/cost_number | property_name} [, {integer_value | string_value} ])
```

The `MemoryMBs` property must be set to some value.

After that it appears to be necessary to recompile the query in question (for example using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` on a dev box, or using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` if that hint is acceptable for later production use).

It is easy to tell that the `WHATIF` value "took" by the fact that it influences the `<OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties>` values in the XML execution plan.